# Installing grounding rods...without hitting something critical?

Tags: grounding

Is there an easy way to figure out where a safe location for grounding rods are?
I don't want to hit a sewer line or a water line.
Our house is on a raised foundation and has a crawlspace underneath.
The electric panel is outside on the back wall of the house.

Comment: Is there room and use, either under the house or outside it, for a large area of flat concrete?

Comment: If it is new construction inside the footing is a good place. With a remodel that requires an additional rod outside close to the service so you have room to drive the 8' rod. Remember gutter drains usually sit next or close to the foundation I drove a rod through one of these once.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: call Dig-Safe , assuming you're in the USA.  The number is 811 , at least in the states I checked very briefly.

That will take care of gas & electric and I believe water lines.  Tracing the sewer line, if not covered by Dig-Safe, should be pretty easy as it's almost always a straight run from wherever the pipe leaves your house to the street.

Comment: While the number is now standard, the name of the service varies wildly, even within states.  For instance yours is several New England states.   Largely it's a 7-letter name because the service used to be the corresponding 7-digit number.